# Word is placed on a new line even if there's enough space on the old line

Tags: bug, status-declined, editor, ios, stacks-editor

Is it expected behavior that words automatically moved to the next line even when there's enough space on the old line?

See animation below for clarification (no "return" key pressed during the experiment):

> [image]

Same behavior is observable in StacksEditor for RichText mode only. Markdown modes work normally, i.e. word jumps back to the upper line.

iPadOS 17.0.3
Apple Safari / Google Chrome 117.0.5938.108

Comment: Seems perfectly reasonable behavior to me. You're adding text to the _beginning_ of a long string, and it's moving that to the next line. Adding a space to that string _later_ doesn't undo the explicit line break that's been added. You can "fix" this behavior by simply not doing that.

Comment: (As an aside, I don't see that behavior, so even though I don't see a problem with the way it's working for you, I wonder if it's something more localized: your OS, browser, on-screen keyboard, etc.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand not doing what? Just typing the text? For instance, notepad.exe works in a different (but expected!) manner, the word jumps back to the old line in the same scenario.

Comment: And it works the expected way for me, too. I'm suggesting that instead of typing your character right at the `h`, here --> `https://long/url` you add a space or carriage return yourself before you start adding words to the beginning of a URL that you have no intention of keeping as a prefix to the URL. I don't know why you would _intentionally_ type words with your cursor at the beginning of a URL.

Comment: Anyway, if engineers have any hope of investigating or fixing the "problem" they're going to need more information as I suggested - What OS? What browser? Is that a native on-screen keyboard or 3rd party? etc.

Comment: @AaronBertrand this wasn't intentionally, I just wanted to add some words before the link and found that weird behavior. BTW on Windows Chrome works as expected, seems like an iPadOS Chrome issue.

Comment: This... is definitely _not_ normal, and not something I'd call "reasonable" either; there's no reason I can see that textual line breaks should be added on visual overflow/ word wrap. [Here's how it looks for me on Windows 10 Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5M6qy.gif) (though you've already checked as much). No idea whether the fault for this lies with the SE editor, mobile Chrome, or iPadOS though.

Comment: @zcoop98 Well, I was just guessing at what that thing is doing. I can't reproduce, so, no idea. But at the core, "when I do this non-standard thing by accident, in this one specific environment, this weird thing happens" I think it's perfectly reasonable to conclude that one workaround is to not do that non-standard thing or be okay with the weird thing that happens. I really suspect this is a local software issue and not something that is in the editor but that (so far) only happens for αλεχολυτ.

Comment: Is it a visual bug in the editor's live preview or is it actually reflected in the markdown?

Comment: I can reproduce this in both the classic editor and the Stacks editor on my iPad running Safari on iOS 17. To answer my own question, switching view from rich text to MD does remove the extra lines, so it’s not that the code is wrong. But the purpose of the rich text view is to show what the post will look like live and it’s doubtful that posting would retain the extra lines. Technically, the MD won’t, either since there’s no double space at the end of the row.

Comment: @Sonic are you sure that [ios] tag is relevant here? iPadOS is slightly different thing. It seems we need someone with iPhone to reproduce the issue

Comment: Reproduced on macOS Sonoma 14 using Safari 17.0. But not when using Chrome 117, Edge 117, Firefox 118, or Opera 103.

Comment: [Screen capture on macOS Sonoma 14 using Safari 17.0](https://imgur.com/Rk9GI10)

Comment: WebKit strikes again? I've heard that Safari has some weird behaviors that don't occur in other browsers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We (the team maintaining the [Stacks Editor](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor)) decided to mark this issue as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) because it is likely a regression introduced in the latest versions of WebKit. This behavior is reproducible in any `textarea` elements (not just our editor).

There is not much we can do from our end but to wait for the issue to be resolved by the WebKit maintainers.

Comment: To others reading this answer who may not believe this is a valid application of the tag: the extended tag wiki for [tag:status-declined] says, *In the case of bugs, this usually comes up because the bug is not caused by the software that powers the sites themselves - such as if the problem is with the browser being used. If it would be more effective for the developers of the browser or tool causing the problem, the report will generally be declined.*